# Python: Filter values with multiple criteria and lists

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe where I want to filter two columns (boxes and type). One of those columns is a list (type).

```
df = data.frame(boxes = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
                val  = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8),
                type = c("honey","bread","coffee","bread","honey","coffee"))
```

This is not working. It gives me no matches:

```
df[(df['boxes'] == 1) &
(df['type'] == ("honey","coffee"))]
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried and, &,|. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `R` and `python` , there are multiple small differents. Here we have `isin` in `pandas`

Also good to mention, the dataframe you create is under `R` not `pandas`.

> `R : data.frame`   `pandas : DataFrame`

```
df_sub=df[(df['boxes'] == 1) & (df['type'].isin(["honey","coffee"])].copy()
```

Also in `R` change your code to below with `%in%`

```
df[(df['boxes'] == 1) & (df['type'] %in% c("honey","coffee"))]
```